# MySQL + Windows VISTA / 7 = Crashes with Eclipse RCP + Datanucleus app

Tags: mysql, eclipse, windows-vista, crash, datanucleus

I'm having a big problem with MySQL + Datanucleus + Windows Vista / 7.

THE Problem is so SEVERE, the MySql Server Shuts Down!

PROBLEM OCCURS:

- with DN 1.0.0.m3 + MySQL 5.1.x (LOCAL) + Vista.
- when performing deletePersistent of an object that has a LIST in the structure (a deletePersistentAll of the LIST is issued BEFORE deleting the main object)

NO PROBLEM:

- with objects that don't have LISTs (or SETs?) in the structure.
- with LINUX / Windows XP.
- with postgreSQL.

We are in pain here!!! :-\

Thanks.

marco

Answer (score 0):

1). You are using an ancient version of DataNucleus.

2). You quote no exceptions, and if they are the same as you mentioned on the DataNucleus forum then the issue is almost certainly configuration of MySQL on Windows.